# How to allow sorting on a protected worksheet in VBA code for Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

How can I protect the content of an Excel spreadsheet, but allow the user to sort the columns?  Please see my code below.  I keep getting the "The cell or chart you're trying to change is on a protected sheet..." error message.  I don't want them to be able to change anything in the table except be able to sort.

```vb
Public Sub ProtectCells()

    Dim lastRow, lastCol As Long
    Dim columnLetter As String
    Dim sc As SlicerCache
    Dim sl As Slicer
        
    lastRow = Range("A7").End(xlDown).Row
    lastCol = Range("A7").End(xlToRight).Column
    columnLetter = Split((Columns(lastCol).Address(, 0)), ":")(0)

    With ActiveSheet

        .Protect Password:="abcd", DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, _
        Scenarios:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
    End With

    ' Establish a range that can allow edits on the protected worksheet.
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect "abcd"

    Range("A7:" & columnLetter & lastRow).Select
    ActiveSheet.Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add _
        Title:="WIP", _
        Range:=Range("A7:" & columnLetter & lastRow)
        
    'Unlock slicers
    For Each sc In ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches
        For Each sl In sc.Slicers
            sl.Locked = False
        Next sl
    Next sc
        
    With ActiveSheet
        .Protect Password:="abcd", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:= _
            True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
        .EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
    End With
    
End Sub
```

I've been using all the advice that I have found on the internet pertaining to this using the "Allow Sorting does not work" as my search. This is why I have "AllowEditRanges.Add" in my code above. I would think that the "Select locked cells" option would work along with allow sorting would work, but it doesn't.

Almost every answered question is from 2019, or later.  Since they're old answers, I assume that the silver bullet has already been discovered.  If anyone knows what that is, please help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new code below allows sorting and keeps the sheet protected.

```
Public Sub ProtectCells()

    Dim lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long
    Dim columnLetter As String
        
    lastRow = Range("A7").End(xlDown).Row
    lastCol = Range("A7").End(xlToRight).Column
    columnLetter = Split((Columns(lastCol).Address(, 0)), ":")(0)

    With ActiveSheet

        .Protect Password:="abcd", DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, _
        Scenarios:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
        .EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
    End With
'
'    ' Establish a range that can allow edits on the protected worksheet.
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect "abcd"
    ActiveSheet.Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="Range1", Range:=Range( _
        "A7:" & columnLetter & lastRow)
        
    With ActiveSheet
        .Protect DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:= _
            True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
        .EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
    End With

End Sub
```